# xsd error: Access to the path is denied

Tags: .net, xsd.exe

I am trying to update an xml schema by using the xsd tool. The script running it looks like this:

@ECHO OFF

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe" ArchiveServiceConfiguration.xsd /classes /language:CS /namespace:"SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.ArchiveServiceConfiguration"

PAUSE

But there is a writing error both when running it as user and as administrator. Any suggestions? I might add that it the old file is under source control in team explorer.

D:\AK2\ArchiveService\CommonLogicModule\SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.ArchiveServiceConfiguration>xsd.exe ArchiveServiceConfiguration.xsd /classes /language:CS /namespace:"SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.ArchiveServiceConfiguration"

Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.1432]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Writing file 'D:\AK2\ArchiveService\CommonLogicModule\SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.ArchiveServiceConfiguration\ArchiveServiceConfiguration.cs'.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'ArchiveServiceConfiguration'.
  - Access to the path 'D:\AK2\ArchiveService\CommonLogicModule\SI.ArchiveService.CommonLogic.ArchiveServiceConfiguration\ArchiveServiceConfiguration.cs' is denied.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArchiveServiceConfiguration.cs might already be there and possibly used by VS (Do you have VS running?) . Change the output path of xsd.

Comment: I tried deleting the file and that works. I think the source control write protects it.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the read-only attribute of the file or close it. Look at the `attrib /?` DOS command.

Comment: Thank you. I renamed it to .old and xsd was then able to create a new file.